# How can I (in effect) subtract Time in Excel when the answer will be greater than 24 hours?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to write an Excel sheet which calculates Flexi-time hours remaining to be worked in a week.

The user may enter the time they started work and the time they ended work, and the spreadsheet will calculate how many hours they worked that day. This is (obviously) a simple formula, `=C4-B4`.

However, if I try to take this same approach to calculate the hours remaining to be worked in a week (i.e. 37 - 11, or, more accurately, `=TIME(37,0,0) - TIME(11,0,0)`) then it does not work, because the time is automatically converted to 24 hour time, so the answer, 26, would in fact become 2.

Is there a way to work with hours which gets around this issue whilst preserving the precision of times?

I have seen similar spreadsheets made where the user may simply calculate hours worked in decimal (i.e. 18.5 for 18 and a half hours) however I would like to preserve the accuracy a TIME format can provide.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What does your spreadsheet look like right now? I assume you have `Time In | Time Out | Total Time` and `Total Time` is `=(C4-B4`)*24`. With that, can't you just `=37-<Total Time>`?

Comment: As I said, `Total Time` is simply `=C4-B4` - why would it be `=(C4-B4)*24`?

Comment: See below answer.  Internally, time is a stored as decimal days (and can be greater than 1).  Just multiply by 24 to convert to hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to convert to decimal, but you can keep having the users enter as time...

```
=37-D4*24
```

Behind the scenes, your time is just a decimal (of a portion of a day), so by multiplying by 24 you will calculate the number of hours...

EDIT:
If you want to simulate "Time" formatting, you can use this (note, it's no longer a number, so can't be used in downstream calculations):

```
=TRUNC(37-D4*24)&":"&TEXT(ROUND(MOD(37-D4*24,1)*60,2),"00")
```

Comment: What is `A1:A3` exactly? The hours worked is `C4-B4` (where `C4` is `=TIME(17,0,0)` and `B4` is `=TIME(09,0,0), for example. This would give an answer of `08:00` (in, lets say, `D4`) 

If I try `=37-VALUE(D4)*24` it does not work, and gives me 12:00 as an answer, when it should be giving an answer of 29:00 in that case.

Comment: Answer was written before cell addresses or layout was provided.  Time is Time of Day, not hours.  Whatever cell =37-VALUE(D4)*24 is in should be formatted as a decimal--you will see your 12:00 change to 29.0.  Oh, and VALUE() is uncessary.  I will update.

Comment: This has the problem of losing accuracy. i.e. `37h - 6:08h` should become `30:52h`however it shows `30:87` which is confusing to the user. 

Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: `30.87` is 30 hours and 52 minutes (rounded).

Comment: Yes. I know. I did not say it was incorrect, simply that is confusing to the user. 

For example, were the result `30.25` the user may think it was `30h 25m`when in fact it is `30h 15m`

Comment: Actually, please try the new answer (not sure I was supposed to change an accepted answer, but trust me this is alot better!).  This version retains the numeric values and is much easier to understand.

Comment: Your new answer does not seem to work.

Comment: The `=TRUNC etc.` one worked perfectly, though.

Comment: works for me, oh well, I'll change it back :)